# React : How to create a Drag Handle with draggable?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, draggable

I am unable to find an answer on how to make a `react` `component` draggable only when the `Drag Button` is clicked (`Clicking anything inside the element wont trigger the drag event`)

Here is the `Material UI` `JSX` code:

```
<Box
    draggable={false}
    onDragStart={onDragStart(props.data)}
>

    {/* Title */}
    <div>Draggable Element 1</div>


    {/* Button : Drag Handle */}
    <div className="test-drag-handle">

        <IconButton // MUI Button
            draggable
            onClick={(e) => {}}
            sx={{
                color: 'rgb(19, 140, 126)',
                caretColor: 'rgb(19, 140, 126)'
            }}
        >
            {/* Drag Handle: Icon */}
            <Icon
                path={mdiArrowAll}
                size={'22px'}
                className=""
                style={{
                    color: 'rgb(19, 140, 126)',
                    caretColor: 'rgb(19, 140, 126)'
                }}
            />
        </IconButton>

    </div>


    {/* Button : Edit */}
    <Box sx={{
        mr: 1
    }}>

        ... Edit Button

    </Box>


    {/* Button : Clone */}
    <div className="mr-4">

        ... Clone Button

    </div>


    {/* Button : Delete */}
        ... Delete Button

</Box>
```

and it looks like this:
[image]

I want to make the element draggable only when the `Drag Button` is clicked

Clicked anything inside the element will not trigger the `drag` event, except the `Drag Button`

[image]

What should I do it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the state when the button was clicked.

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

const toggleDraggable = () => {
    setDisabled(!disabled);
  };

<Box
    draggable={disabled}
    onDragStart={onDragStart(props.data)}
>

    {/* Title */}
    <div>Draggable Element 1</div>


    {/* Button : Drag Handle */}
    <div className="test-drag-handle">

        <IconButton // MUI Button
            draggable
            onClick={(e) => {toggleDraggable();}}
            sx={{
                color: 'rgb(19, 140, 126)',
                caretColor: 'rgb(19, 140, 126)'
            }}
        >
            {/* Drag Handle: Icon */}
            <Icon
                path={mdiArrowAll}
                size={'22px'}
                className=""
                style={{
                    color: 'rgb(19, 140, 126)',
                    caretColor: 'rgb(19, 140, 126)'
                }}
            />
        </IconButton>

    </div>


    {/* Button : Edit */}
    <Box sx={{
        mr: 1
    }}>

        ... Edit Button

    </Box>


    {/* Button : Clone */}
    <div className="mr-4">

        ... Clone Button

    </div>


    {/* Button : Delete */}
        ... Delete Button

</Box>
```

Comment: onMouseDown={() => setBlockDrag(index)}
onMouseOut={() => setBlockDrag(null)}

==> this worked best for me for multi draggable blocks